# Want to convert doc into ps format through programming

Tags: linux, postscript, libreoffice

I want to convert doc to ps(post script) format programatically.I know there is an utility available in LibreOffice that does this conversion but I don't want to install Libreoffice on the Client machine instead I want to reuse the source code of LibreOffice to develop this utility.I know it is a very cumbersome task but at least if someone can give me any kind of basic approach on how to do this or any other way doing it programatically.

I want it for Linux OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Linux or any non Mac-os.

Comment: OK - please try and be more specific in your original question, i.e. state required platform(s) and tag accordingly.

Comment: Just for Linux would be fine...and also I made a typo it is post script not print script..

Comment: OK - hit the <edit> button above and fix your question please.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this.I guess now you have understood completely what I am trying to do. Can you provide me any basic approach to do this?

Comment: Or any other related reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can get away with striping the DOC importer and postscript generator from libreoffice  just for this - you'd need a considerable army in men/hours.

Either the ready made Python script which runs on top of Libreoffice you already mentioned - if you want it to work at all - I hope you know it does not need a graphical display to run, and it can be done as "command line" (usually you will want to keep LibreOffice running in the background).

If you really want to roll your own app for this, you should check the code for koffice/calligra instead - It will be built around Qt architecture - I had not looked at it recently, but it will be more modular and reusable than libreoffice's - re-using the doc-importer and ps exporter from calligra is a job I believe could be done by a single person along some reasonable time (that will varies according to the person familiarity with the Qt/C++ enviroment it is built in)
URLs:

http://www.calligra.org
http://community.kde.org/Calligra/Building

Comment: Can you give me some more details on this. The mechanism how I should proceed or any other related details that you can give about Calligra.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't. I've built it once, and it did compile - and Qt using projects are usually organized enought hat you have a good chance of being able to use the .doc import filter straight from code you write. It is still a lot of work, and facing your needs, I would not hesitate in installing LibreOffice and  use it to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You might run into considerable trouble because they're not really compatible "formats" (in an abstract sense).

DOC is, of course, a document. So  it contains text, style tables, ... hierarchical information pertaining to the logical structure of the artifact.

PS is not (necessarily) a document. It is a page-description. It contains information pertaining to the visual image of the artifact.

So you really need to *render* a PS from  DOC, not just *convert*. You'll need to make line-breaking decisions, draw tables, calculate spacing for justification, and placement of embedded images. It's a big job.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you provide any way for doc to pdf using the utility of Calligra.

Comment: It looks like the Calligra homepage has its own forum. They can probably give you a good answer there.